# viewDidLoad() and global variables

Tags: swift, xcode

Inside my viewDidLoad() function I have some simple code to read in a plist to a variable:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

  let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Kana List", withExtension: "plist")!
  let kanaData = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
  let kanaList = try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: kanaData, options: [], format: nil)

}
```

if I then want to use this kanaList variable in another Swift file, how do I do it? This kanaList variable is likely to be an array of dictionaries.

Comment: It's not possible to use an internal variable from another file. You can make is a global variable and then you can use the list via class object.

Comment: There are several ways to achieve this. You could make a singleton class that holds the variable with a getter and a setter.

You could use dependency injection in your other class and inject the value you need.

Comment: Well what’s the common way people will do this when they load some data from a plist and then want to access it globally?

Comment: You may want to look into UserDefaults and shared instances. For starters: https://medium.com/@nimjea/userdefaults-in-swift-4-d1a278a0ec79

Comment: Or you could instantiate these global objects on your `AppDelegate` and pass them everywhere (dependency injection)

Answer (score 0):

Inside the VC class, define it as a class variable, and then reference it using self.variableName

```
var kanaList: [YourObject] = [YourObject]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Kana List", withExtension: "plist")!
let kanaData = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
self.kanaList = try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: kanaData, options: [], format: nil)

}
```

HOWEVER: This is usually an anti-pattern, and hard to maintain. If you need an array of data objects, manage it with a Model class, and have your VCs (and other classes) access it from there. This way, you don't have to pass duplicates of the same array around.

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you elaborate a bit more. Do you mind showing some sample code on how to do this?